# Git show --color not preserving color when posting to Microsoft Teams

Tags: python, git, colors, microsoft-teams

I'm using gitpython and pymsteams to post a git commit message to Microsoft Teams. The local log output shows the diffs in color as expected. However, Teams will not show the color, no matter the --color parameters I specify.

Does anyone know how to preserve the colors here to post to Teams in full?

## Code:

````
import pymsteams
from git import Repo

myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("Teams Webhook URL")

repo = Repo(os.environ[ "OX_REPO_NAME" ])
diff = repo.git.show("--color",os.environ[ "OX_REPO_COMMITREF" ])

msg = '''\
Changes to `%s`:

```diff
%s```
''' % ( os.environ[ "OX_NODE_NAME" ],
diff, 
)

myTeamsMessage.text(msg)
myTeamsMessage.send()
````

### UPDATE ADAPTIVE CARD

I've tried using the adaptive card example from Microsoft but get the exact same output in Teams. [No color, instead weird formatting 33m shows up][1]

```
url="Teams Webhook URL"

payload2 = {
    "type":"message",
    "attachments":[
       {
          "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
          "content":{
             "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
             "type":"AdaptiveCard",
             "version":"1.2",
             "body":[
                 {
                 "type": "TextBlock",
                 "text": msg
                 },
                 
             ]
          }
       }
    ]
 }

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload2))


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv0t4.png
```

Comment: Maybe you share the output that you want highlighted?

Comment: Could you please share the repro step and screenshot what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Using connector card it is not possible to show color. Please have a look at this  [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=connector-md%2Cconnector-html#format-cards-with-html). Instead you can use adaptive card which has the color property in TextBlock - [link](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/TextBlock.html)

Comment: I just want the git commit diffs to show up (red for subtracted and green for added config). Here's an example.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/swu3wj8svadow5n/Screen%20Shot%202022-01-13%20at%202.13.01%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: The steps to reproduce just include running that script and seeing the output in Teams not being colored.

Comment: Right but color is not at all supported in ConnectorCard so it will not have it. So you will need to handle it manually with Adaptive TextBlock and send it as Adaptive card

Comment: I tried using Adaptive Cards (I edited the post, please see the addition), but I get the exact same output. Do I have the right format?

Comment: Please use [color property](https://www.adaptivecards.io/explorer/TextBlock.html) in adaptive card. You can use single color for one Textblock. Adding a small example -  { "type":"message", "attachments":[ { "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive", "content":{ "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json", "type":"AdaptiveCard", "version":"1.2", "body":[ { "type": "TextBlock", "text": "color text", "color": "good" }
] } } ] }

Comment: So there is no way to post a git commit message that natively shows color (red if config has been deleted and green if it has been added)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RichTextBlock](https://www.adaptivecards.io/explorer/RichTextBlock.html) to  get different colors. It is not possible to post a git commit message with the colors. You have to mention the colors explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

- To copy the colors:

  - If you are using Putty (or something similar should have a similar option):

    - to copy the formatting and not just (by default) the text :
    - in Putty setting, under: Window--Selection--Copy

      - you need to check [x] "Copy to clipboard in RTF as well as plain text"
    - after this you can then :

      - paste into a Word document (or other things accepting RTF formats) and you'll see colors "close to" the ones you had on your Putty terminal.
  - Unfortunately, "Teams" itself will strip the formatting away (colors, some spaces, etc).

    - It even can't copy it's own formatting! (colored words you did in Teams itself):

      - You can copy it, and then paste it out of Teams into a rtf-enabled program (such as: Word)
      - But when you paste it instead in another Teams section: all the formatting will be stripped as well.
    - A workaround is to : instead, upload into the Teams discussion the Word document containing the properly formatted text (that you made with the method above...)

About the weird formatting:

- The [33m "weird formatting" you see is in fact part of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code that git used to tell your terminal to start displaying the following characters in Yellow.
- On "Unixes terminals" the Ansi escade sequence:

  ```
    Esc + [ + 33 + m
  ```

  tells the terminal to change the foreground color to yellow (and thus what comes afterwards should appear as yellowish text, if that terminal understands it and has a yellow color available)
- A shell exemple to show this:

```
    printf 'normal color\033[33mThis is yellow\033[0m normal again...'
```